# "What was all that about" usage

Tags: phrase-usage, idioms, usage, phrases, idiomatic-language

Let's say someone is using a vending machine with his eyes closed.

A second listener finds this behavior strange (obviously). So when the first person is done with the vending machine, she asks, "What was all that about?"

Is *what was all that about* used correctly in this situation? Why or why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a British English speaker, I find "What was that all about?" perfectly normal, after something said or done that I find inexplicable, either as a direct question to the sayer or doer, or, very often, as a rhetorical question to another bystander. In the latter case a possible response might be a shrug, or rolled eyes, or both.

Comment: I think @michael is right to use the word "inexplicable".

Answer (score 0):

Not really, but possible. "What was that all about" is usually used for scenarios which the person doesn't really know the situation that occurred. In this case you witnessed the whole thing. A better and more simple one is:

> what were you doing?

Comment: Is "What was that?" another good alternative?

Comment: yes that sounds fine @alexchenco

Answer (score 0):

For me using a vending machine with eyes closed is odd, but not odd enough to merit  *"What was all that about?"*

Had the person been banging on the machine, or had they been shouting at it, then the question could be used.

I might use the question when someone does something that I consider to be outside normal behaviour but for behaviour that is loud or disturbs other people.